# How to send multiple params in node js in get petition?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am tryng to send an array as a param so I have the following code

```
var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(url);

    request.get('http://localhost:8090/saveURL/'+myJsonString, function(req, res,body) {
        console.log(body);
    })
```

How I can send params with node ?

EDIT

I changue my request petition , now I am using this.

```
request.get({
   url: 'http://localhost:8090/saveURL/',
   qs: { param1: JSON.stringify(url)}
      },
      function(req, res,body) {
        console.log(req);
        console.log(body);
      }
    )
```

This is correct ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend performing this with `POST` method and not `GET`, which is more appropriate for altering data on the server.
Also, the URL length is limited and if your data is very large, it won't work.

For instance:

```
request.post(
    'http://localhost:8090/saveURL/',
    { json: { key: 'value' } },
    function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log(body)
        }
    }
);
```

Replace `{ key: 'value' }` with a POJO (a normal JS object).

Answer (score 1):

According the the `request` [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request), you can use `qs` to pass an object of query params:

```
request.get({
   url: 'http://localhost:8090/saveURL/',
   qs: { param1; 'a', param2: 'b'}
  },
  function(req, res,body) {
    console.log(body);
  }
)
```

Comment: I update the question ! How I can see the url that I created wit this manner?

Comment: I believe you can check `req.url` in your callback